# django urlpattern wrong? need to accept 2 different parameters

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm working on building a django app for a small little game I'm building to integrate it. Instead of re-writing my app to use django's membership system I've added my small little game login system to the django site. My issue is with my ChangePassword url pattern.

```
url(r'^ChangePassword/(?P<userID>[0-9]+)/(?P<token>/?$)', changepassword, name='Change Password'),
```

I get the following error in the terminal while trying to go to the page.

> Not Found: /members/ChangePassword/11/aw7MdMn4DaFoPp6W4P+c4IZWXRAF9g==
>   [14/Oct/2016 16:53:53] "GET /members/ChangePassword/11/aw7MdMn4DaFoPp6W4P+c4IZWXRAF9g== HTTP/1.1" 404 3294

Am I missing a regex or do I have the pattern wrong? I've been going through user docs and question on here and found a solution yet. It needs to accept the userID and a special token so we know that we can reset/change the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex pattern for the token:

```
(?P<token>/?$)
```

Will match an optional forward slash `/` that *ends* the url. In other words it will match `/members/ChangePassword/11/` or `/members/ChangePassword/11//`.

You will need to modify so that it captures the characters in your token. Since it looks like `base64` encoding, which includes `[A-Z][a-z][0-9][+/=]`, you should be able to edit as follows:

```
(?P<token>[A-Za-z0-9+/=]+$)
```